# Get JSON data using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular cli and trying to get data from json file but it is not working.Also i m trying to get the specific data value from json file but that is not working anybody find that mistake from the code:
my code:

app.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { BackendApiService } from './services/backend-api.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    public arry;

    constructor(private backendApiService: BackendApiService) {}

    profile = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        arry = this.backendApiService.getUser()
            .subscribe(data)
            .srchlink
            .map(function(srchlink) {
                return srchlink.slink;
            }); 
    }

    testings() {
        console.log(arry);
        console.log(data.autocomp.sval);
    }
}
```

backend-api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BackendApiService {
    private _url="assets/employeedata.json";
    public comUrl;

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    getUser() {
        return this.http.get(this._url)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

employedata.json

```
{
    "srchlink": [
        { "slink":"google.com"},
        { "slink":"yahoo.com"}           
    ],
    "autocomp": [ 
        { "sval":"Table"},
        { "sval":"Back"},
        { "sval":"Drag"},
    ] 
}
```

Comment: What erro are you getting? What's your angular and angular-cli version?

Comment: i m using @angular/cli: 1.4.4

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? May be `./assets/employeedata.json`.

Comment: path is correct but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Updated to include the request from your comment.

Your use of [`subscribe`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) is incorrect. The parameter you're passing (`data`) should be a callback function that will be given the data that you can then process. The following changes to `ngOnInit` should work for you:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.backendApiService.getUser()
        .subscribe(data => {
            arry = data.srchlink
                .map(function(srchlink) {
                    return srchlink.slink;
                });

            autocompv = data.autocomp
                .map(function(autocomp) {
                    return autocomp.sval;
                });
        });
}
```

The main thing to note is that `http.get` in your example is an *asynchronous* operation, which is the reason you have to use a callback function within `subscribe` in order to get access to the data itself.